# Python Basic Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

Hello I made this calculator in Python, I know it's pretty basic but I want your opinions if I made it well or not, and if you find any mistakes or not.
P.S ( I know I could do another better than this one if I looked in internet but I want to evolve that's why I'm here )

```
#Commands
print("Operations that you can use:")
print("Addition: +")
print("Subtraction: -")
print("Multiplication: *")
print("Division: /")
print("Exponentiation: **")
print("Radicalization: **(1/")
print("\n")

#Variables
x = None
y = None
z = None
ce = 0

while ce < 1:

# Inputs
    x = float(input("First Value: "))
    y = input("Operation: ")
    z = float(input("Second Value: "))

# If
    if '+' == y:
        add = float(x) + float(z)
        print(add)
    elif '-' == y:
        sub = float(x) - float(z)
        print(sub)
    elif '/' == y:
        div = float(x) / float(z)
        print(div)
    elif "**(1/" == y:
        rad = float(x) **(1/float(z))
        print(rad)
    elif "**" == y:
        exp = float(x) ** float(z)
        print(exp)
    elif '*' == y:
        mul = float(x) * float(z)
        print(mul)
    print("Continue or Exit?")
    ce = int(input("    0    or   1  : "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me offer the following rewrite of your program and then let's walk through it:

```
names = {'Addition' : '+',
         'Subtraction' : '-',
         'Division' : '/',
         'Exponentation': '**',
         'Radicalization': '**(1/'
        }

print("Operations that you can use:")
for op in names:
    print(op, names[op])

ops = {
       '+' : (lambda x, y: x + y),
       '-' : (lambda x, y: x - y),
       '*' : (lambda x, y: x * y),
       '/' : (lambda x, y: x / y),
       '**' : (lambda x, y: x ** y),
       '**(1/' : (lambda x, y: x ** 1.0 / y),
       'na' : (lambda x, y: 'Unknown binary operator')
      }

ce = 0
while ce != 1:
    x = float(input("First Value: "))
    y = input("Operation: ")
    z = float(input("Second Value: "))

    op = ops.get(y, 'na')
    print(ops[op](x, z))

    print("Continue or Exit?")
    ce = int(input("    0    or   1  : "))
```

- It seems unnecessary to define `x`, `y` and `z` to be `None` so we just define them inside the main loop.
- The `ops` dictionary stores a symbol of the operator and the actual implementation in a lambda function. It also stores a special `'na'` value to represent any unknown operator; this is useful in the main loop where we return that key if we don't find what the user gave us as input.
- The key difference and main idea here is a *data-driven solution*. That is, notice how we've put the supported operators into data structures. This way it's easier to make changes and to maintain the program, e.g., when you add a new binary operator, you don't have to touch the logic of your calculator, just add a new element into your data structure.
- There's no explicit if-elif chain anymore, yay! Such chains are often annoying to write and it's always a potential code smell. No matter how experienced you are, it's one of those things where it's easy to make a human error and write something you didn't mean to, but it can be tough to discover the bug.